# v-btn-toggle in vuetify returning the wrong value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an array of environments and I want to use v-btn-toggle to create a button of each environment, the problem is that when I `console.log(this.envSelected)`, it prints out the index, not the actual environment.. My goal is to make the button look like it's clicked.
I already tried `:value="envText", value=${environments[envText]}`

```js
<template lang="pug">
  v-btn-toggle(
    v-model="envSelected"
    v-on:change='updateSelectedEnv()'
    )
    v-btn(
      v-for="(envText, index) in environments" 
      :key="index"
      vulue={envText}
      ) {{ envText }}  
</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
       envSelected:"QA",
       environments: ['DEV', 'IDEV', 'QA', 'STAGE', 'UAT', 'PROD', 'IDEV2', 'QA2'],
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`v-btn-toggle`'s value (and thus `v-model`) is the index of the selected item. To resolve the value, use the index (`envSelected`) as a lookup into `environments[]`:

```js
console.log(this.environments[this.envSelected])
```

Comment: My goal is to make the button look like it's been clicked, and for that I need the value of the button to be the actual environment text not the index. I'm trying to figure out why value = index and not value = environment text

Comment: `v-btn-toggle` only supports index values.